# Search with Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel, search

I am trying to make a search for multiple models. I have set up the route and html form and I am successfully receiving the data in my controller. Now, I want to query multiple columns and get the result as an eloquent or array.

What is the proper way of achieving this?

```
public function search(Request $request) {
     $searchTerm = $request->search;

     // I want to search..
     Content::where('value', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')->get();
     BlogPost::where('value', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')->get();
     // etc..
}
```

Comment: Can you add semicolon end of this line `$searchTerm = $request->search;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add `like` to the queries. Then, if you want an array, use `toArray()` method and [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to merge results:

```
$result1 = Content::where('value', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')->get()->toArray();
$result2 = BlogPost::where('value', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')->get()->toArray();
$result = array_merge($result1, $result2);
```

If you want to get a collection, just get the data and merge it with [`merge()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-merge) helper.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a question. I tried using `{{ $result }}` but I can't get it with this method. What is the proper way of achieving it? Also, using `merge()` instead of `array_merge()` throws me 'Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\merge()'

Comment: @senty here `$result is` an array or a collection, so you need to iterate over it with `foreach ($result as $oneRow)` and then get the data inside  the loop with `{{ $oneRow->value }}`. You can look at structure of `$result` by putting `{{ dd($result) }}` into the view.

Answer (score 0):

You just put the results in a variable?

```
public function search(Request $request) {
     $searchTerm = $request->search

     // I want to search..
     $contents = Content::where('column', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')->get();
     $blogs = BlogPost::where('column', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')->get();
     // etc..
}
```

Comment: Is there any different with @senty question? I saw different only column and value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `merge()`

```
 $contents = Content::where('column', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')->get();
 $blogs = BlogPost::where('column', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')->get();
 $contents->merge($blogs);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-merge

another option is union:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#unions